# Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 728 ms

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, native

Well I know that this question is asked many times here and on other platforms as well. And these answers did help me as well but my problem is not solved fully yet. I tried

```
if(isDevMode())
    enableProdMode();
```

This reduce time from 16000ms to 728ms. Now, how can I remove this delay?

And got this runtime error:

> error cannot enable prod mode after platform setup.

I'm using

- Ionic CLI 3.1.5
- Cordova CLI 7.1.0

Comment: You are using -prod flag while creating build for android?

Comment: yes I'm using it still no use ;

Comment: And now event fire time increases on every build